# Advantage of visiting two Nazi concentration camps?

Tags: germany, berlin, munich

I visited the Sachsenhausen (Saxon House) concentration camp last year, when I was in Berlin. I am likely to be in Munich next year. Is there much to be gained from visiting Dachau as well? Or are the exhibits at both sites similar?

Comment: I do not think this question can be answered unless one knows what you value and/or expect to be gained from such a visit. I fear the question is opinion-based hence why I am closing it.

Answer (score 6):

Depends on why you would want to go there. The sites are both *historical* sites and *memorials*. I would say that for getting information, a good book is better than a guided tour through the ruins of a camp. The actual site has more emotional impact, but going to two sites doesn't have twice the emotional impact.

- There might be specific exhibitions or guided tours. For instance, Dachau has one on Dutch prisoners right now.
- I guess you wouldn't ask that way if you had a family connection to one of the sites.